# iText - adding Image element generates a corrupt PDF file

Tags: image, pdf-generation, arrays, itext

I'm using iText® 5.2.1 ©2000-2012 1T3XT BVBA and Integration Designer 8.0 to create a PDF file that is exported in an byte array.

I am creating a document with a fair amount of text and want to add a logo at the beginning.

Part of the code that is adding the image is as follows:

```
BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
byte[] decodedBytes = decoder.decodeBuffer(Stringovi.SLIKA1);
Image image1 = Image.getInstance(decodedBytes);
image1.setAbsolutePosition(30f, 770f);
image1.scalePercent(60f);
document.add(image1);
```

The input image is in byte array format because of the system requirements.
The rest of the document consists of different tables with various content and it's all text.
When I add the image in the before mentioned way the program finishes and i get an byte output that i run trough a Base64 decoder. Resulting PDF can not be opend and the error shown is:

```
 "Error [PDF Structure 40]:Invalid reference table (xref)"
```

I can't see where my mistake is so if anybody could be so kind and point me in the right direction I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: Please provide the broken document for analysis.

Comment: Please note that all 5.2.x versions have been removed from the official download repositories: http://itextpdf.com/changelog/52 I quote: **IMPORTANT: we've removed all 5.2.x versions from SourceForge because of a major issue with large PDF files. Please don't use iText 5.2.0 or 5.2.1!**

Comment: Here is the broken document [file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6746035/base64%20-%20text%20plus%20the%20logo%20image.pdf)

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Tried with other versions of iText and the same problem was present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document you presented as a "broken PDF file" is not a complete PDF file. It doesn't end with `%%EOF`, it doesn't have a cross-reference table,... It's a PDF document that isn't complete.

This means that you don't have the following line in your code:

```
document.close();
```

If you do have this line, it isn't reached. For instance: an exception is thrown causing the code to jump to a `catch` clause, skipping the `close()` operation.

The error message saying `Invalid reference table (xref)` is consistent with that diagnosis. This isn't a problem caused by iText. It's a problem caused by bad coding: not closing the document and/or not dealing with exceptions correctly.

Comment: Well i do have the line and it is reached. After the line i have a `System.out` that prints that the document is closed.

Comment: In that case something is removing the end of the PDF after you've closed the document. For instance: maybe you're copying the bytes in a way that only the first X bytes are taken into account and the subsequent bytes are thrown away. In any case: the PDF you've shared isn't a full PDF: it's half a PDF.

Comment: Well now i feel a bit silly. I was getting the right output, but while doing the copy/paste from Integration Designer the basic copy didn't select the whole output so I was missing the end of the file. Thank you for your help, it made me realize my mistake.